# SQL - How to count yes and no items

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008.

I am writing a query where I need to count how many yesses (1) and how many nos (0 or NULL).

```
SELECT B.Brand, B.BrandID, COUNT(M.ModelID) AS TotalModels
FROM Brands B LEFT JOIN Models M ON B.BrandID = M.BrandID
GROUP BY B.Brand, B.BrandID
ORDER BY B.Brand
```

There's another field called IsBestValue in the Model table that will be NULL, 0, or 1.  I want to be able to count TotalBestValueYes, TotalBestValueNo, and TotalBestValueNULL.

A long time ago...I use to use something like ..

```
(CASE WHEN IsBestValue = 1 END) // ADD ONE TO TotalBestValueYes
(CASE WHEN IsBestValue = 0 END) // ADD ONE TO TotalBestValueNo
(CASE WHEN IsBestValue = NULL END) // ADD ONE TO TotalBestValueNULL
```

Is using CASE in the fashion a good idea? Bad idea? Overkill?

Is there are better way to count yesses and nos and NULLs?

Comment: Looks fine to me (the case method) case when x = 1 then 1 else 0 end

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with using the CASE like that if this is what you mean.

```
SELECT  B.Brand,
        B.BrandID,
        COUNT(M.ModelID) AS TotalModels,
        SUM((CASE WHEN M.IsBestValue = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) TotalBestValueYes,
        SUM((CASE WHEN M.IsBestValue = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) TotalBestValueNo,
        SUM((CASE WHEN M.IsBestValue IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) TotalBestValueNull,
FROM    Brands B
        LEFT JOIN Models M ON B.BrandID = M.BrandID
GROUP BY B.Brand,
        B.BrandID
ORDER BY B.Brand
```

Answer (score 7):

The is the perfect **case** for `CASE` (pun intended).

`CASE` is a very well optimized operator and was designed for just such a usage scenario.

The normal syntax for a conditional count is along the lines of:

```
SELECT SUM (CASE WHEN x=y then 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'XequalsY'
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and reassurance. So often, what seems like a good idea turns out to be a horrible idea. It's nice to know that I was doing it right so long ago and can continue doing it this way.

Answer (score 2):

```
select count(nullif(IsBestValue, 0)) as TotalBestValueYes,
       count(nullif(IsBestValue, 1)) as TotalBestValueNo,
       count(case when IsBestValue is null then 1 end) as TotalBestValueNull
```